# data-export-data-type="all" not working for exporting data from all pages in bootstrap table plugin?

Tags: bootstrap-4, datatable, export-to-csv, bootstrap-table

I am using [bootstrap table extended](https://bootstrap-table.com/docs/getting-started/introduction/) with bootstrap 4.
I am trying to use export button to download the data from all pages.

css file:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://unpkg.com/bootstrap-table@1.17.1/dist/bootstrap-table.min.css">
```

scripts:

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js" integrity="sha256-FgpCb/KJQlLNfOu91ta32o/NMZxltwRo8QtmkMRdAu8=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-UO2eT0CpHqdSJQ6hJty5KVphtPhzWj9WO1clHTMGa3JDZwrnQq4sF86dIHNDz0W1" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JjSmVgyd0p3pXB1rRibZUAYoIIy6OrQ6VrjIEaFf/nJGzIxFDsf4x0xIM+B07jRM" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/tableexport.jquery.plugin/tableExport.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/tableexport.jquery.plugin/libs/jsPDF/jspdf.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/tableexport.jquery.plugin/libs/jsPDF-AutoTable/jspdf.plugin.autotable.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/bootstrap-table@1.17.1/dist/bootstrap-table.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/bootstrap-table@1.17.1/dist/extensions/export/bootstrap-table-export.min.js"></script>
```

These are the attributes of bootstrap table that I am using:

```
<table id="table" 
data-toggle="table"
data-pagination="true"
data-show-toggle="true"
data-show-columns="true"
data-show-fullscreen="true"
data-height="650"
data-page-size="12"
data-page-list="[12,24,36,48,All]"
data-show-export="true"
data-export-data-type="all"
data-export-types="['json','csv', 'txt', 'sql', 'excel']"

data-click-to-select="true"
data-toolbar="#toolbar"
>
```

It is mentioned in their [documentation](https://bootstrap-table.com/docs/extensions/export/) that using export data can be tweaked with:

```
Attribute: data-export-data-type

type: String

Detail:

export data type, support: ‘basic’, ‘all’, ‘selected’.

Default: basic
```

But when I use

```
data-export-data-type="all"
```

then it didn't change anything and download data only from current page.
I had read almost all the content over internet but nothing works .

Answer (score 1):

Could please provide some more informations about your setup ?
The full code with data would be great, the best would be to use the [editor](https://live.bootstrap-table.com) to create a example.

Without that information we cant help you, because the [example](https://live.bootstrap-table.com/example/extensions/export.html) works pretty fine with `data-export-data-type="all"`.

Answer (score 0):

I suppose, the problem is here:

```
   data-page-list = "[12,24,36,48,All]"
```

Have you tested all syntax variations? What comes to mind:

`[12, 24, 36, 48, 'ALL']` `[12, 24, 36, 48, 'all']` ... etc

any variations, but value **all** is first suspect and isn't (int)